# how to initialize bootstrap tooltip everywhere in vue js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli, bootstrap-popover

I tried to initialize bootstrap tooltip in vue cli globally.
so I placed this lines of code in App.vue 'mounted hook':

```
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
let tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

here I get bootstrap is undefined error.
and

```
this.$jQuery('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').Tooltip();
```

has no error but doesn't work.

I import libraries in 'main.js' like so:

```
// popper
import popper from "vue-popperjs/dist/vue-popper.min";
// bootstrap
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css";
import bootstrapJs from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min";

Vue.use(bootstrap);
Vue.use(popper);
Vue.use(bootstrapJs);
```

and jQuery has been imported above of all.
I'm using vuejs 2 and bootstrap 5. BS doc recommend using the first code. Maybe my approach is not the proper one to do this or my imported libraries are wrong. I can't figure out.
so any answer appreciated :-)